# Assign property value from another property value that is in a related table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a table called `PRODUCT`, in which the `Price` of a Product is stored.
Because I know that the price of a product can change at any time, I have a table called `ORDER`, which holds the `Quantity` of the product that is being ordered by someone, and the `TodaysPrice`, which is the price that should be extracted from the column `Price` in the moment where the transaction is being done.

The problem is, I don't know how to extract a property's value and assign this value to another property in LightSwitch.

---

So far, what I've managed to think is to include this in the `Order_Created()`:

`this.Order.SelectedItem.Price = this.Order.SelectedItem.Product.Price;`

But the code above doesn't work, I get this exception:

`NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code`

I'm not sure if the is correct, any help would be much appreciated. I want to know how can I do this in LightSwitch 2011 with Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably running when *SelectedItem*, or *Product*, does not currently have a value. You should always check for null before referencing any property of an entity.

Like this (notice how each entity is checked before referencing any properties of that entity:

```
if (this.Order != null) 
    && (this.Order.SelectedItem != null) 
    && (this.Order.SelectedItem.Product != null)
{
    this.Order.SelectedItem.Price = this.Order.SelectedItem.Product.Price;
}
```

The *Order_Created* method is not the right place to have this code, because at the point when the *Order* is created, you don't yet know which Product is going to be *selected*. The correct place to put this code is in the *Product_Changed* method, so that when the *Product* is selected (or changed), the *Product*'s current price then gets enetered in the *Order*.

Just on another note, unless you've simplified your tables for the example, I think you're missing a table. An *Order* will usually will have things like an associated *Customer*, a *Date* etc. It will also have a collection of *OrderLines* (or some similar name) It's the *OrderLine* that should have the product/qty/price details, not the *Order* itself.